# Memory leak issue with PHP 5.3

Tags: php, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm developing a code that's supposed to go through all records in a database and run 'save()' on each of them.

The thing is, it's giving me a 'Fatal error: Allowed memory size exhausted' error (see below)

current memory usage: 19592272

current memory usage: 20944968

current memory usage: 22361824

current memory usage: 23649968

.
.
.

current memory usage: 274071160

current memory usage: 275354880

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 276824064 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in/home/lestest/public_html/garratt/phproad/modules/phpr/classes/phpr_extensible.php on line 94

I read this was an issue with any PHP version that's below 5.3 (I'm using PHP 5.3.2). I follow advices from articles like http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/262#comment-940 and https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48781I, and made sure to destruct() and unset() the object after each loop to free the memory, but I don't know why it's still keeping memory. Can anyone point out what should be changed with the code?

Below is my code:

```
<?php
     class ProductSave_Products extends Backend_Controller {

          public $implement = 'Db_FormBehavior, Db_ListBehavior';
          public $form_model_class = 'ProductSave_Model';

          public function index()
          {
          $this->app_module_name = 'Products';
          $this->app_page_title = 'Save';

          $obj = new ProductSave_Model();

          $ids = Db_DbHelper::queryArray('select id from shop_product');


          foreach($ids as $row)
          {
               $product = Shop_Product::create()->find($row['id']);
               $product->save();
               $product->__destruct();
               unset($product);
               print "current memory usage: ". memory_get_usage() . '<br/><br/>';


           }


       }


   }

?>
```

Here is my Db_Helper class code:

```
<?php

class Db_DbHelper
{
    protected static $driver = false;

    public static function listTables()
    {
        return Db_Sql::create()->fetchCol('show tables');
    }

    public static function tableExists($tableName)
    {
        $tables = self::listTables();
        return in_array($tableName, $tables);
    }

    public static function executeSqlScript($filePath, $separator = ';')
    {
        $fileContents = file_get_contents($filePath);
        $fileContents = str_replace( "\r\n", "\n", $fileContents );
        $statements = explode( $separator."\n", $fileContents );

        $sql = Db_Sql::create();

        foreach ( $statements as $statement )
        {
            if ( strlen(trim($statement)) )
                $sql->execute($statement);
        }
    }

    public static function scalar($sql, $bind = array())
    {
        return Db_Sql::create()->fetchOne($sql, $bind);
    }

    public static function scalarArray($sql, $bind = array())
    {
        $values = self::queryArray($sql, $bind);

        $result = array();
        foreach ($values as $value)
        {
            $keys = array_keys($value);
            if ($keys)
                $result[] = $value[$keys[0]];
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public static function query($sql, $bind = array())
    {
        $obj = Db_Sql::create();
        return $obj->query($obj->prepare($sql, $bind));
    }

    public static function fetch_next($resource)
    {
        return self::driver()->fetch($resource);
    }

    public static function free_result($resource)
    {
        self::driver()->free_query_result($resource);
    }

    public static function queryArray($sql, $bind = array())
    {
        return Db_Sql::create()->fetchAll($sql, $bind);
    }

    public static function objectArray($sql, $bind = array())
    {
        $recordSet = self::queryArray($sql, $bind);

        $result = array();
        foreach ($recordSet as $record)
            $result[] = (object)$record;

        return $result;
    }

    public static function object($sql, $bind = array())
    {
        $result = self::objectArray($sql, $bind);
        if (!count($result))
            return null;

        return $result[0];
    }

    public static function getTableStruct( $tableName )
    {
        $sql = Db_Sql::create();
        $result = $sql->query($sql->prepare("SHOW CREATE TABLE `$tableName`"));
        return $sql->driver()->fetch($result, 1);
    }

    public static function getTableDump( $tableName, $fp = null, $separator = ';' )
    {
        $sql = Db_Sql::create();
        $qr = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM `$tableName`");

        $result = null;
        $columnNames = null;
        while ($row = $sql->driver()->fetch($qr))
        {
            if ( $columnNames === null )
                $columnNames = '`'.implode( '`,`', array_keys($row) ).'`';

            if (!$fp)
            {
                $result .= "INSERT INTO `$tableName`(".$columnNames.") VALUES (";
                $result .= $sql->quote( array_values($row) );
                $result .= ")".$separator."\n";
            } else
            {
                fwrite($fp, "INSERT INTO `$tableName`(".$columnNames.") VALUES (");
                fwrite($fp, $sql->quote( array_values($row) ));
                fwrite($fp, ")".$separator."\n");
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public static function createDbDump($path, $options = array())
    {
        @set_time_limit(600);

        $tables_to_ignore = array_key_exists('ignore', $options) ? $options['ignore'] : array();
        $separator = array_key_exists('separator', $options) ? $options['separator'] : ';';

        $fp = @fopen($path, "w");
        if (!$fp)
            throw new Phpr_SystemException('Error opening file for writing: '.$path);

        $sql = Db_Sql::create();

        try
        {
            fwrite($fp, "SET NAMES utf8".$separator."\n\n");
            $tables = self::listTables();

            foreach ($tables as $index=>$table)
            {
                if (in_array($table, $tables_to_ignore))
                    continue;

                fwrite($fp, '# TABLE '.$table."\n#\n");
                fwrite($fp, 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `'.$table."`".$separator."\n");
                fwrite($fp, self::getTableStruct($table).$separator."\n\n" );
                self::getTableDump($table, $fp, $separator);
                $sql->driver()->reconnect();
            }

            @fclose($fp);
            @chmod($path, Phpr_Files::getFilePermissions());
        }
        catch (Exception $ex)
        {
            @fclose($fp);
            throw $ex;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generates an unique column value
     * @param Db_ActiveRecord $model A model to generate value for
     * @param string $column_name A name of a column
     * @param string $base_value A base value of the column. The unique value will be generated
     * by appending the 'copy_1', 'copy_N' string to the base value.
     * @param bool $case_sensitive Specifies whether function should perform a case-sensitive search
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getUniqueColumnValue($model, $column_name, $base_value, $case_sensitive = false)
    {
        $base_value = trim($base_value);
        $base_value = preg_replace('/_copy_[0-9]+$/', '', $base_value);

        $column_value = $base_value;
        $counter = 1;
        $table_name = $model->table_name;

        $query = $case_sensitive ?
            "select count(*) from $table_name where $column_name=:test_value" :
            "select count(*) from $table_name where lower($column_name)=lower(:test_value)";

        while (self::scalar("select count(*) from $table_name where $column_name=:test_value", array(
                'test_value'=>$column_value
            )))
        {
            $column_value = $base_value.'_copy_'.$counter;
            $counter++;
        }

        return $column_value;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a SQL query string for searching specified fields for specified words or phrases
     * @param string $query Search query
     * @param array|array $fields A list of fields to search in. A single field can be specified as a string
     * @param int $min_word_length Allows to ignore words with length less than the specified
     * @return string Returns a string
     */
    public static function formatSearchQuery($query, $fields, $min_word_length = null)
    {
        if (!is_array($fields))
            $fields = array($fields);

        $words = Core_String::split_to_words($query);

        $word_queries = array();
        foreach ($words as $word)
        {
            if (!strlen($word))
                continue;

            if ($min_word_length && mb_strlen($word) < $min_word_length)
                continue;

            $word = trim(mb_strtolower($word));
            $word_queries[] = '%1$s like \'%2$s'.self::driver()->escape($word).'%2$s\'';
        }

        $field_queries = array();
        foreach ($fields as $field)
        {
            if ($word_queries)
                $field_queries[] = '('.sprintf(implode(' and ', $word_queries), $field, '%').')';
        }

        if (!$field_queries)
            return '1=1';

        return '('.implode(' or ', $field_queries).')';
    }

    public static function reset_driver()
    {
        self::$driver = false;
    }

    public static function driver()
    {
        if (!self::$driver)
        {
            $sql = Db_Sql::create();
            return self::$driver = $sql->driver();
        }

        return self::$driver;
    }

    public static function escape($str)
    {
        return self::driver()->escape($str);
    }
}
```

?>

Thank you

Comment: Your problem is almost certainly in your `DbHelper` Class. Can you post some of the code from that?

Comment: Can I ask why you need to do `create()` on the shop product each time?

Comment: leemo - I pasted my db_helper class code

Comment: Ohgodwhy - I think I need that for creating an object for a product. To be honest I'm not too sure what purpose it serves either. Do you have any way that might not involve using create()?